# VmRSS is growing

Tags: c++, memory, memory-leaks

In my application VmRSS is increasing but VmSize is not increasing. Is this symptom of memory leak?

I have checked my application with Valgrind tools, but it does not detect memory leaks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

RSS stands for *Resident Set Size*. That's the amount of memory that your process is actively using, and is mapped in real RAM (not swapped out to disk).

If the RSS is going up, but your total virtual image size is stable, then you're not allocating more memory but making more active use of the memory you already allocated. That in itself isn't a problem, it's just a sign that your process is doing a lot of stuff with an increasing amount of the memory it already allocated.